# Sorting dictionaries alphabetically inside the list

Tags: python, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting my dictionaries in the list.

Unfortunately the sorted function doesn't work the way I want it to.

(below is my code)

```
names_to_sort = [{'Karwinski', 'Bandyciak', 'Anoniasz'}, {'Aajacykowa', 'Tomaszek', 'Kochanowa'}] #sample names

names_to_sort = sorted(names_to_sort)

print(names_to_sort)

#expected result
# [{'Aajacykowa', 'Kochanowa', 'Tomaszek'}, {'Anoniasz', 'Bandyciak', 'Karwinski', } ]
```

Dictionaries inside each other should be sorted alphabetically.
Additionally, dictionaries should be organized according to the first name in the dictionary. So if the first name in Dictionary 1 is `'Anonias'` and the first name in Dictionary 2 is `'Aajacykowa'` then the dictionaries should swap places because `'Aajacykowa'` is in the alphabet before `'Anonias'`.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: those aren't dictionaries, right?

Comment: What you have here is a list of sets. A set is an unordered data structure, meaning you can not sort it. You're better off using a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a lexical ordering of a list of **sets** (not dictionaries - those contain key-value pairs) of names by first ordering the names, then ordering the sets of names.
For this you'll have to turn the sets into sorted lists (luckily `sorted` already does this for you), which may then be sorted - first sorting the names, then sorting the lists of sorted names lexicographically using `sorted`:

```py
names_to_sort = sorted(map(sorted, names_to_sort))
```

yields the desired result (except obviously not as sets); if you want sets, simply convert the lists back to sets:

```py
names_to_sort = list(map(set, names_to_sort))
```